# Link to tab using jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have two tabs that I hide and show using jQuery. But now I have to make a link to `files` tab which is in the same page. I try with this:
`<a href='#files' target='_blank'>Files</a>`

But how to make to be selected `files` section? Now, it's `application` section because of class `.current` which is by default.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.app-tabs span').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('.app-tabs span').removeClass('current');
    $('.applications-tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');

  });
});
```

```css
.applications-tab-content{
    display: none;
}
.applications-tab-content.current{
    display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="app-tabs" id="app-tabs">
  <span class="application current" data-tab="application">Data</span>
  <span class="files" data-tab="files">Files</span>
</span>

<div id="application" class="applications-tab-content  current"> some text here </div>
<div id="files" class="applications-tab-content"> some files here </div>
```

Comment: I can't understand your problem. Explain what you want.

Comment: There are 2 tabs on page - `application` and `files` and I'm using jquery when you click on one of the tabs, to make it `current` and display it. I have a text in this page that says : `files` and have to be a link to `files` section. But when I make it like that:`<a href='#files' target='_blank'>Files</a>`, I need to add class `current` to `files` section. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the tab visible by setting the `current` css class like in your click handler code. So, instead of only set the `href` and `target` attributes in your link, you need a click handler on it as well.

```
$(document).on("click", "#id-of-your-link", function (event) {
   var tab_id = $(this).attr("href");
   event.preventDefault();

   $('.app-tabs span').removeClass('current');
   $('.applications-tab-content').removeClass('current');

   $(".app-tabs").find('span[data-tab="' + tab_id.replace(/'#', '') + '"]').addClass('current');
   $(tab_id).addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but maybe it's better idea to make separate view for these files, because if someone wants to see them and click on the link when he/she  is not on the page, it won' t work?